# Can LVM and Traditional Partitions Coexist?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, lvm, partition

Can you set up a machine in which different drives are formatted as either LVM volumes or as traditional partitions and mix and match the two? For e.g. have the LVM volume mounted as `/` and `/home` and `swap` and then have a separate hard drive with a traditional ext3 primary partition mounted as `/home/user1` or `/var`?

Any advantages or disadvantages to having a mixed system if it is feasible?

Answer (score 4):

Sure - they can co-exist without issue.

The only problem I see in the plan is increased complexity. I typically want to have my filesystems be 100% on "standard" partitions or 100% on LVM partitions.

Comment: Not only is it possible, it's downright normal, at least on RH boxes where GRUB (sometimes) can't cope with `/boot` being on LVM.  But as EEAA says, there's a cost in added complexity, and you shouldn't assume that cost without a good reason.